# Grouping an Array of Integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, group-by

So I have an assignment I am working on and I can't for the life of me figure out how to complete the last part.

I have an array of numbers, and I have to sort those numbers which I have and then I have to group them by how many of each there are. Thats the part I am getting stuck on.

I am doing it all in one document for this assignment:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Arrays For Days</title>
<style>
    body {
        line-height: 1;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    }
    p.headings {
        font-style:italic;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-decoration: underline;">Sorting and Grouping Arrays</h1>
    <br>
    <p class="headings">Starting List of Numbers:</p>
    <p id="startNumbers"></p>
    <br>
    <p class="headings">Numbers Sorted:</p>
    <p id="arraySorted"></p>
    <br>
    <p class="headings">Array Sorted and then Grouped:</p>
    <p id="arrayGrouped"></p>

    <script>

        var numbers = [1, 5, 17, 4, 9, 3, 1, 17, 32, 5, 3, 27, 9, 18, 3, 12, 67, 18, 32, 1, 19, 21, 1, 17];
            //printed original numbers to HTML element using document.getElementById
        document.getElementById("startNumbers").innerHTML = numbers;
            //used .sort method, with a comparative function using a-b, so if a is less than b then the result...
            //should be a sorting of lesser to greater.
        numbers.sort (
            function(a, b) {
                return a - b;
        });
            //then I printed the now sorted numbers to matching HTML element using document.getElementById
        document.getElementById("arraySorted").innerHTML = numbers;




        document.getElementById("arrayGrouped").innerHTML = output;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just trying to get the numbers to show up on my page like this:

1:4, 3:3, 4:1, 5:2, 9:2, 12:1, 17:3, 18:2, 19:1, 21:1, 27:1, 32:2, 67:1

which is possible but I keep only finding examples not quite like this and having to do with a bunch of other stuff with arrays i dont need for this assignment. thank you anyone for the help :-)

Nathan L.

Comment: If you can find a way to sort without using arrays, you'll win all the codes.

Comment: yeah unfortunately I have to do it this route :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `.filter()` to get the `.length` of the current element filtered from original array. One option to remove duplicates from the resulting array is to pass array to `Set` constructor, convert `Set` back to array with `Array.from()`.

```
document.getElementById("arraySorted")
.innerHTML = Array.from(new Set(numbers.map(n => `${n}:${numbers.filter(_n => _n === n).length}`)));
```

Comment: almost it seems to put a 1:4 four times for each number 1. and looks like this: 1:4,1:4,1:4,1:4,3:3,3:3,3:3,4:1,5:2,5:2,9:2,9:2,12:1,17:3,17:3,17:3,18:2,18:2,19:1,21:1,27:1,32:2,32:2,67:1

Comment: hm, it works but I think I need to find a more older JS way of sorting and grouping instead of a 1 line fixer. I like what you did though, and it works marvelously. but i am trying to stay relatively vanilla and basic.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using just the `Array.prototype.reduce` function. To group the numbers, you need to add elements to new array, and compare each number to the last item of the new array. If it is the same, you just add 1 to the accumulator of the last item, else you create a new element for the new number. I hope the following code makes it a bit clear:

```
var groupedNumders = numbers.reduce(function(ac, currentValue) {  // ac for accumulator
    if (currentValue === ac[ac.length - 1][0])
      ac[ac.length - 1][1] += 1;
    else 
      ac.push([currentValue, 1])
    return ac
  }, [[numbers[0], 0]])
```

If you are confused by what `Array.prototype.reduce` does, refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b).

To create a printable string, you could reduce the array again:

```
var output = groupedNumbers.reduce(function(s, a) {return s + a[0] + ":" + a[1] + ", "}, "")
```